# Reference 2 columns on seperate sheet, and return value in third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to create a tracking sheet for my office's service schedule.  Each month, I get an updated service schedule from our service department, which I copy and paste into a spreadsheet called "Services".  I have another sheet called "Important Dates"  What I need to do, is put a formula in columns B, C, and D of "important dates" which will look at Column A, find the value of column 'Important Dates'!A2 in Column B of "Services", and check the type of services in column D, and return the date in Column F.

I've tried doing it with VLookup, but I can't check two locations with it, I'm not familiar enough with Index to get it to work, and I really want to avoid using macros for something I'm sure can easily be done with formulas.

Important Dates Sheet:

[image: Important Dates Sheet]

Services Sheet:

[image: Services Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide any info on your issue, here is an example how to perform multiple lookup with array formula:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$10,MATCH($A1&LEFT(B$1,1),Services!$B$1:$B$10&Services!D$1:$D$10,0))
```

Note: Array formulas are applied by hitting **Ctrl**+**Shift**+**Enter**.

If you can't catch-up with the formula above you will need to provide some sample data.

Comment: Hi Boris, thank you for your help.  I wasn't able to upload a picture due to my being a new member.  Stackoverflow automatically converted my image to a link.  If you click the link, you can see the picture of the two worksheets in the workbook.  I would be happy to upload an example workbook as well, but I don't see how I can do that.  I notice that David Makogan has converted my links back to images, so thank you David for that.

Comment: Thanks for example. Please see the edit that works for rows 1 trough 10 which you can edit yourself.